# How to tell Eclipse library location

Tags: c, linux, curl

I need to write simple `c` programm that transfers files using `ftp`. I have installed `curl` library on my `Ubuntu` machine using `aptitude`. I found header `/usr/include/curl/curl.h` and include it to to my project. Currently I got a lot of messages like `undefined reference to curl_global_init` while trying to build project. According to my understanding I need somehow to tell my `Eclipse` where is `curl` library. So, where is my curl library? And what is the right place to tell eclipse about this library?

Comment: You add `-lcurl` to the linker flags. Preprocessor, compiler, assembler and linker flags should be available somewhere under a "Build" or "Project" or "Compiler" menu (or a general "Settings", who knows?)

Comment: but how to know where is my curl library on my Ubuntu?

Comment: It's right there in `/usr/lib` (or `/usr/local/lib`). But you don't need to know that -- if it's in one of the standard library locations, then the linker will find it on its own.

Comment: I see directory /lib and usr/local/lib on my PC. What is difference between them?

Comment: @userXXX well... what kind of difference?

Comment: There are 3 library dirs on my system - /lib , /usr/lib , /usr/local/lib . Why so many lib dirs and when each of them are used for?

Comment: @userXXX 1. Because that's how it developed over the long course of computing; 2. `/lib` generally stores libraries installed by default, but you can really put a library to any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and use `Properties` In the window that opens you should see a dialog which has, among other things a `C/C++ Build -> Settings` where you can change all kind of settings, like include paths, linker paths, and others.

Answer (score 0):

> According to my understanding I need somehow to tell my Eclipse where is curl library

In Eclipse **Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC Linker-> Libraries; add [-lcurl or -l]** option to your linker

> So, where is my curl library?

/usr/lib or **lib64** (no need to worry about lib - GCC will take care of it)

binary: **/usr/bin/curl**

I hope this is helpful

Regards,

Mitesh